# Oracle, update column in table 1, when related row does not exist in table 2

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, left-join

I have seen many answers that will update a table 1 when rows exist in table 2, but not one that works using a LEFT JOIN in selecting the rows, (for better performance). I have a solution to the update, but it will perform badly as it uses NOT IN.

So this SQL will update the tables as required, but looks to be very costly when run against large tables making it difficult to use.

```
update header 
set status='Z' 
where status='A' 
and header.id not in (
    select headerid 
    from detail 
    where detail.id between 0 and 9999999
);
```

Now I have a well performing query using a LEFT JOIN which returns the correct ids, but I have not been able to insert it into an update statement to give the same results.
The select statement is

```
select header.id 
from header 
left join detail on detail.headerid = header.id 
where detail.headerid is null 
and header.status='A'
```

So if I use this in the update statement as in:

```
update header 
set status = 'Z' 
where header.id = (
    select header.id 
    from header 
    left join detail on detail.headerid = header.id 
    where detail.headerid is null and header.status='A'
)
```

Then I fail with:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I am expecting multiple header.id to be returned and want to update all these rows.

So I am still searching for a solution which will update the returned rows, using a well performing SQL select to return rows in table header, that do not have related rows in the detail table.

Any help would be appreciated, otherwise I will be left with the badly performing update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting multiple header ID & the sub query returns multiple ID as you expected you should use `IN`

Try this

```
Update 
    header 
Set status = 'Z' 
Where 
    header.id IN (select 
                      header.id 
                  From
                      header 
                  Left join 
                      detail 
                  On 
                      detail.headerid = header.id 
                  Where 
                      detail.headerid is null 
                  And 
                      header.status='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the condition on the *outer* table in the subquery.  I am more comfortable writing this logic as:

```
update header h
    set status = 'Z'
    where not exists (select 1
                      from detail d
                      where d.headerid = h.id
                     ) and
          h.status = 'A';
```

If performance is an issue, indexes on `detail(headerid)` and `header(status, id)` and help.

Answer (score 0):

typical, the next place I looked, I found an answer...

```
update header set status='Z' where not exists (select detail.headerid from detail where detail.headerid = header.id) and status = 'A'
```

Oh well, at least its here if anyone else wants to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states your subquery is returning more than one rows and you are using a = sign in your update query. = sign is not allowed if your query returns more than one records use either IN, NOT IN , EXISTS, NOT EXISTS as per your requirement